# Next.js only runs getServerSideProps once, not fetching new data when accessed by next/router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a Next.js app with SSR where I export a `getServerSideProps` async function as follows:

```
export const getServerSideProps = getGenericServerSideProps([""]);
```

`getGenericServerSideProps` is an async function that is imported from another file that makes a call to a headless CMS to fetch data:

```
export const getInitialProps = (slices: string[], ...callbacks) => async (
    context: NextPageContext
): Promise<CmsPageResponse> => {
    for (const callback of callbacks) {
        if (Array.isArray(callback)) {
            continue;
        }
        callback();
    }
    const lang = getLangFromContext(context);
    const { slug } = context.query as { slug: string[] };

    const paths = getPaths(slug, lang);

    return await getCmsPageManager([...slices, ...paths].join("/"), lang);
};

export const getGenericServerSideProps = (slices: string[], ...callbacks) => async (
context: NextPageContext
): Promise<any> => {
    const appConfiguration = getAppConfiguration();
    const props = await getInitialProps(slices, callbacks)(context);
    return { props: { ...props, appConfiguration } };
};
```

If I access the page via URL (e.g. to directly to app/page1) it runs `getServerSideProps` and give me fresh data.

If I try to access that same page a second time, but through a router link:

```
<Link href={ROUTES[Pages.Home]} as={ROUTES[Pages.Home]}><a>Link</a></Link>
```

It does not execute `getServerSideProps` and gives me old data.

How can I force Next.js to execute `getServerSideProps` every time the page is accessed? Right now, it seems like it is using the props that were created when the app was built (if I re-build the app, the new props and old props are synced, but if I make changes to the data in the CMS, the pages display old data on second render).

Comment: `getServerSideProps` will be called on each request to the page it is on. Do you have any caching going on somehow?

Comment: @juliomalves I don't have any particular caching, however, I tested if it actually calls `getServerSideProps` on a page change via Router (with console logs) and it does not seem to call it. It is called only once, the first time the page loads, and after that it doesn't enter that function at all.

Comment: How are you checking `getServerSideProps` gets called? Are you checking the terminal where you started the Next.js server for the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving an answer with what was wrong, since I have since figured it out.

Apparently the project had set in next.config.js custom Cache Control headers for all `json` files requested with a very long invalidation and Next.js evidently applied this to the JSON files that were requested via AJAX after the page was initially loaded with GSSP.

Check your next.config.js folks.